# Convert Date string to unix time stamp

Tags: c++

I have a string in the form "20190930_141414" which is the date 2019 09 30 14:14:14. How can I convert this to the unix time stamp in utc?

Comment: Maybe you could extract substrings and then convert those substrings into numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams with [get_time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) and [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/) to convert it to a time_t object (time since the epoch).

```
struct std::tm lTM;
std::istringstream lTimestamp( "20190930_141414" );
lTimestamp >> std::get_time = ( &lTM, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S" );
std::time_t lEpoch = mktime( &lTM );
```